# htaccess protection against Ppoxies websurfing websites

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I put this code in my .htaccess, but I can sill put up my site with hide.me and other free web surfing websites?? is their away to fix this??

```
RewriteEngine on   
RewriteCond %{HTTP:VIA} !Chrome\ Compression\ Proxy
RewriteCond %{HTTP:XROXY_CONNECTION}    !^$ [OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR}     !^$ [OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP:FORWARDED-FOR}       !^$ [OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED}         !^$ [OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP:VIA}                 !^$ [OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP:FORWARDED}           !^$ [OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP:USERAGENT_VIA}       !^$ [OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X_FORWARDED_FOR}     !^$ [OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP:PROXY_CONNECTION}    !^$ [OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP:XPROXY_CONNECTION}   !^$ [OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_PC_REMOTE_ADDR} !^$ [OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_CLIENT_IP}      !^$     
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
```

Comment: did you try increasing loglevel to see what is being matched?

Comment: That was just a miss paste... fixed

Answer (score 0):

Would this work because a website isn't supposed to visit the site just users??

```
<Files *>
Order Allow,Deny
from all
Deny from .org
Deny from .com
Deny from .net
</Files>
```